# Is there a Python Function to specify the weights I want to use for KNN?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I am using the scikit-learn KNeighbors Regressor in Python.  I was reading an article where they defined that k was 3 and the nearest neighbor was weighted 50% but the further two were weighted 30% and 20%, respectively.  I have been looking all over for documentation on how to do something of the sort using callable weights but I am not finding much regarding how to write a callable function like this.  Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html

> class sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, *, weights='uniform', algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, p=2, metric='minkowski', metric_params=None, n_jobs=None)
> ...
>
> weights{‘uniform’, ‘distance’} or callable, default=’uniform’
> Weight function used in prediction. Possible values:
> ‘uniform’ : uniform weights. All points in each neighborhood are weighted equally.
> ‘distance’ : weight points by the inverse of their distance. in this case, closer neighbors of a query point will have a greater influence than neighbors which are further away.
> [callable] : a user-defined function which accepts an array of distances, and returns an array of the same shape containing the weights.